# which is the Linux command to install a module into the kernel Space?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I compile my Dependent Kernel module for raspberry Pi OS using The build-root 2017. I want to insert my kernel.ko Device driver module into my customized OS (size of this OS less than 100MB).

I tried to `insmod` but its getting error than `first insert dependency module`. I know about the `modprod` command to insert it but how to use is I don't know?

Comment: this question is off-topic.  Look at `modprobe(8)` man page.

Comment: sorry ,but this is the Linux  topic i need some help ,if you know something related to modprobe .than please help me...

Comment: I don't see any `linux` tag... you had better to eliminate all those tags unrelated to your question, that avoid this kind of comments attracting people uninterested or unable to give you a response. If you actually need help, going to the wrong place to ask for it is not good for you.  Nor for us.  Question indeed is not about programming, but about knowing how to insert a module in a running kernel, which I have answered in my previous comment.  Look at `modprobe(8)` which is the linux command to install a module into the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Lot's of Research i have found the two command to install the module into kernel space

1. `insmode module_name`
   -> it is simply install the module into kernel space and not checking any dependency for
   other module .
2. `modprobe module_name`
   -> it is install module into kernel space before that its check the dependency for other
   module.

Comment: Typo: `insmode`vs. `insmod`,

Comment: my bed its `insmod` only